# how to retrieve directories using server-side javascript for ASP

Tags: asp-classic, recursion, directory, jscript

I am trying to retrieve all subfolders recursively into a character-delimited string "list" using server-side Javascript for Classic ASP.  Here is my function that is supposed to do the trick:

```
function hasContent(text) {
if (text == undefined) {
    return false;
} else if (text === undefined) {
    return false;
} else if (text == "undefined") {
    return false;
} else if (text === "undefined") {
    return false;
} else if (typeof text == "undefined") {
    return false;
} else if (text == null) {
    return false;
} else if (text === null) {
    return false;
} else if (text == "") {
    return false;
} else if (text === "") {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
}

function generateActualPath(path) {

try {
    if (!hasContent(path)) {
        return "./";
    } 

    if (!/.+[\\/\\\\]$/.test(path)) {
        path += "/";
    } 

    if (!/^\\./.test(path)) {
        path = "." + path;
    }

    return path;

} catch (e) {
    return "./";
}
}

function retrieveDirectories(dir) {
    try {
        var actualPath = '/' + dir;
        var obj = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        dirs = obj.GetFolder(Server.MapPath(generateActualPath(actualPath)));
        for (var enumm = new Enumerator(dirs.subFolders); !enumm.atEnd(); enumm.moveNext()) {
            if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_&%#]/.test(enumm.item().Name) && enumm.item().Name.trim().indexOf('_') != 0) {
                if (hasContent(Session("directories"))) {
                    Session("directories") += enumm.item().Name + '|';
                } else {
                    Session("directories") = enumm.item().Name + '|';
                }
                retrieveDirectories(enumm.item().Name);
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {} 
}
```

However, I only see the first-level subfolders of "dir" and nothing further, in spite of the recursive call.  What might I be missing here? I verified that "dir" has up to 4 sub-levels of subdirectories that do not begin with "_" and contain legitimate alphanumeric characters per customer requirement.

Comment: I got it, the solution was extremely easy and I didn't even think about it!  Just replace `retrieveDirectories(enumm.item().Name);` with `retrieveDirectories(dir + '/' + enumm.item().Name);`

Comment: Add it as your answer and mark it correct to gain some points.